# Return log of activities inside a Stored Procedure in Teradata

Tags: stored-procedures, teradata

The requirement is to get the log of all the DML statements executed inside a Stored Procedure in teradata. This Stored procedure is being called inside a shell script using BTEQ. The ask is to capture the log of all activities performed inside the shell into a log file in unix. If any error occurs, that also needs to be captured.

The Stored Procedure contains 20 Merge SQLs and i want to see how many rows got affected and how long each statement took. I tried calling the individual merges through BTEQ(instead of calling it in a Stored Procedure), but there is significant time gain if its called inside an SP. Right now, all i can see is that the Stored procedure has been completed successfully.

```
replace procedure SP_Test() 
BEGIN
MERGE INTO T1 using T2  on T1.C1 = T2.C1
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN INSERT (C1,C2,C3) VALUES (T2.C1,T2.C2,T3.C3)
 WHEN MATCHED 
THEN UPDATE                                                                                              
SET                                                                                             
C1                           =             CASE statement 1                                                                                           
C2                           =             CASE statement 2                                 
c3                            =             CASE statement 3 ;
END;
```

inside the BTEQ block of test.sh shell script,

```
bteq << EOF >>LOgFILE.txt 2>&1
.LOGON source/user,password;
.COMPILE FILE = sp_merge.txt;
.IF ERRORCODE  <> 0 THEN .GOTO QUITNOTOK
call SP_Test();
.IF ERRORCODE  <> 0 THEN .GOTO QUITNOTOK
.LABEL QUITOK
.LOGOFF
.QUIT 0
.LABEL QUITNOTOK
.QUIT 2
EOF
```

**Log File currently**
**** Procedure has been executed.
**** Total elapsed time was 2 minutes and 47 seconds.

**Expected Output**
**** Merge completed. 5641191 rows affected.
     5641191 rows inserted, no rows updated, no rows deleted.
**** Total elapsed time was 2 minutes and 45 seconds.

Comment: The info returned to BTEQ is based on the previously executed SQL statement. If you do multiple MERGE you get details for each of them and if you do a CALL you get overall info without details. The usual way to get this info is to catch info for each SQL statement within the SP using GET DIAGNOSTICS ROW_COUNT and insert it into a log table. But afaik there's no way to get the individual INS/UPD/DEL counts, only the overall count. Only in QryLogSteps those three counts can be found.

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing.

Write another procedure and keep an insert statement like this below :

```
REPLACE PROCEDURE <DB_USER>. log_process_run_message   ( IN in_n_process_run_id  DECIMAL(18,0)   , 
                                                    IN in_v_process_name    VARCHAR(30)     ,
                                                    IN in_v_message_txt     VARCHAR(50000)  ,
                                                    IN in_d_message_ts      TIMESTAMP(6)
                                                   )
BEGIN

    BT; -- Begin Transaction 
        INSERT INTO <SCHEMA_NAME>.cop_process_run_message_op
                    (
                     process_name           ,
                     message_txt            ,
                     message_ts
                    ) 
        VALUES      (
                     in_v_process_name      ,
                     in_v_message_txt       ,
                     in_d_message_ts
                    );
    ET; -- End Transaction
END;
```

In your main procedure include an exit handler;

```
DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
    SET lv_sql_state = SQLSTATE;
    SET ln_sql_code  = SQLCODE;
    SET out_status   = 'FAILED';
    ROLLBACK;

    SET  lv_my_mesg = 'Error in : ' || lv_my_mesg || ' - SQLSTATE: ' || lv_sql_state || ', SQLCODE: ' || CAST(ln_sql_code AS CHAR);
    CALL <DB_USER>.log_process_run_message (ln_run_id,lv_err_component,lv_my_mesg,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6));
END;
```

Also define the below variable in your main procedure

```
SET lv_err_component='ur proc name'
```

Now call this procedure inside your main procedure after every merge statement:

```
SET lv_my_mesg ='Merge 1 completed '||CAST(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(0) AS CHAR(19));
CALL <DB_USER>.log_process_run_message (lv_err_component,lv_my_mesg,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6));
```

What this will do is, it will insert a record after successful execution of your merge statements and in case there is an error it will
execute the call statement in the exit handler and will document your error message as well in case there is any.Let me know if this helps.